# Extremal distribution of random variable that averages to a given value

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, linear-programming, convex-hulls

Denote by $\mathcal M$ the set of probability measures over $[0,1]$ that average to $p$. This is a convex set and I am trying to characterize its extreme points. For any $x$, $y$ such that $0\leq x< p< y\leq 1$ define
\begin{align*}
\lambda_x^y = \frac{p-y}{x-y}\cdot\delta_x+\frac{x-p}{x-y}\cdot\delta_y
\end{align*}
where for any measurable $A\subseteq [0,1]$ and $a\in[0,1]$, $\delta_a(A)=\mathbf 1(a\in A)$. Since $\delta_x$ (resp. $\delta_y$) averages to $x$ (resp. $y$) we get that $\lambda_x^y$ averages to $\frac{p-y}{x-y}\cdot x+\frac{x-p}{x-y}\cdot y=p$ and so is in $\mathcal M$.

I am very tempted to say that the extreme points of $\mathcal M$ is the set $\{ \lambda_x^y : 0\leq x< p < y \leq 1 \}\cup \{ \delta_p \}$ without being able to prove it. If I am not mistaking I am supposed to prove that (ignoring the $\delta_x$ component)

- If for some $x$ and $y$ and $a\in[0,1]$, $\lambda_x^y=a \mu+(1-a) \nu$ then $\mu=\nu=\lambda_x^y$.
- For any $\mu\in\mathcal M$ there is a probability measure $\kappa$ over $[0,p]\times[p,1]$ such that $\mu(A)=\int \lambda_x^y(A) d\kappa(x,y)+\mu(\{ p \})\delta_p(A)$ for all measurable $A\subseteq [0,1]$.

For the first point, it is quite clear by positivity of the measures $\mu$ and $\nu$ that their support $\{ x,y \}$, then there is only one probability measure with such a support that averages to $p$ and it is $\mu_x^y$.

For the second statement however it is less clear to me, Maybe one way to proceed is computing the integral
\begin{align*}
\int \lambda_x^y(A) d\kappa(x,y)&=\int \left( \frac{p-y}{x-y}\cdot\delta_x(A)+\frac{x-p}{x-y}\cdot\delta_y(A) \right) d\kappa(x,y)\\
&=\int_{\left(A\cap [0,p]\right)\times [p,1]}\frac{p-y}{x-y} d\kappa(x,y)+\int_{[0,p]\times\left(A\cap [p,1]\right)}\frac{x-p}{x-y}d\kappa(x,y)
\end{align*}
It now feel easier to separate cases $A\subseteq [0,p]$ and $A\subseteq [p,1]$ to set one of the two integral to $0$ but I still don't know how to proceed.

Actually thinking about how I could use it in my research it would be much more powerful to not enforce $x\leq p \leq y$ but just that $p$ is in the convex hull of $\{ x,y \}$ and then we get repetition $\lambda_x^y=\lambda_y^x$ but the of extreme points is the same. This makes $\kappa$ a probability measure over $[0,1]^2$ where we have to be careful assigning $0$ probability to sets $A\times B\subseteq [0,1]^2$ where the convex hull of $A\cup B$ does not contain $p$.

---

Here is the last thing I tried :
Denote $a_x^y=\frac{p-y}{x-y}$, for $\mu \in\mathcal M$ and $A$ measurable
\begin{align*}
\mu(A)&=\int_{[0,p)} \delta_x(A) d\mu(x)+\int_{(p,1]} \delta_y(A) d\mu(y)+\mu(\{ p \})\delta_p(A)\\
&=\int_{[0,p)\times (p,1]} \left(\frac{a_x^y}{a_x^y}\delta_x(A) + \frac{1-a_x^y}{1-a_x^y}\delta_y(A) \right)d\mu\otimes\mu(x,y)+\mu(\{ p \})\delta_p(A)\\
\end{align*}
It feels like we can define $\kappa$ as a function of $\mu\otimes \mu$ and $a_x^y$, I cannot finish the argument though.

Comment: The second item looks like the Krein-Milman theorem in disguise

Comment: @daw : If I am not mistaking, the Krein-Milman theorem says in my case that there is a set of extreme points such that the convex hull will generate $\mathcal M$, I don't see however how it helps determine what those extreme points are.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Indeed the second claim is true. In order to prove this, we introduce some notation:

**1.** We will use *binary splitting process* to establish the desired fact. This will involve splitting the interval $[0, 1]$ into pieces, and we will track this process using binary trees. More precisely, we will consider the binary trees $\mathsf{T}$ such that

1. Each node of $\mathsf{T}$ is a tagged interval of the form $(I, a)$, where $a \in I$.
2. Each internal node $(I, a)$ of $\mathsf{T}$ has exactly two childs $(I_0, a_0)$ and $(I_1, a_1)$, where

   - $I_0 = I \cap (-\infty, a)$ and $I_1 = I \cap [a, \infty)$, and
   - $a_0, a_1 \in I$ such that $a_0 < a < a_1$.

   So, the tagged point $a$ is used to split the interval $I$.

Here is an example of a binary tree:

$$
\small
\begin{gathered}
([0, 1], 0.7) \\
\swarrow \hspace{4em} \searrow \\
([0, 0.7), 0.3) \quad ([0.7, 1], 0.8) \\
\hspace{5.5em} \swarrow \hspace{4em} \searrow \\
\hspace{5.5em} ([0.7, 0.8), 0.72) \quad ([0.8, 1], 0.95)
\end{gathered}
$$

Since knowing the initial interval (the interval in the root) and all the tagged points in $\mathsf{T}$ is enough to reconstruct the entire $\mathsf{T}$, we will usually abbreviate by omitting the interval part whenever no confusion arises. For instance, the above example can be abbreviated as

$$
\small
\begin{gathered}
0.7 \\
\swarrow \quad \searrow \\
0.3 \qquad 0.8 \\
\hspace{3.25em} \swarrow \quad \searrow \\
\hspace{3.5em} 0.72 \qquad 0.95
\end{gathered}
$$

**2.** Now we recursively define $\nu[\mathsf{T}]$ as follows:

1. $\nu[a] := \delta_a$.
2. If $\mathsf{T} = \Bigl( {\scriptsize\begin{gathered} a \\[-5pt] \swarrow \ \searrow \\[-5pt] \mathsf{T}_0 \qquad \mathsf{T}_1 \end{gathered}} \Bigr) $ such that $\mathsf{T}_i$ has root $a_i$ for each $i = 0, 1,$ (in particular, $a_0 < a < a_1$), then

   $$ \nu[\mathsf{T}] = \frac{a_1 - a}{a_1 - a_0} \nu[\mathsf{T}_0] + \frac{a - a_0}{a_1 - a_0} \nu[\mathsf{T}_1]. $$

This notation is related to OP's notation in that, if $x < p < y$, then

$$ \nu \Bigl[ {\scriptsize\begin{gathered} p \\[-5pt] \swarrow \ \searrow \\[-5pt] x \qquad y \end{gathered}} \Bigr] = \lambda^{y}_{x}. $$

Then the following lemma holds:

> **Lemma.** For each binary tree $\mathsf{T}$, there exists a probability measure $\kappa$ on $([0,p)\times(p,1])\cup\{p\}$ such that
>
> $$ \nu[\mathsf{T}](\cdot) = \int_{[0,p)\times(p,1]} \lambda_{x}^{y}(\cdot) \, \kappa(\mathrm{d}x\mathrm{d}y) + \delta_p(\cdot) \, \kappa(\{p\}). $$

This follows by the structural induction together with the following reduction formula

$$ \nu \Biggl[ {\scriptsize\begin{gathered} a \\[-5pt] \swarrow \ \searrow \\[-5pt] a_0 \qquad a_1 \\[-5pt] \swarrow \ \searrow \hspace{3em} \\[-5pt] a_{00} \qquad a_{01} \hspace{3em} \end{gathered}} \hspace{-1.8em} \Biggr]
= \alpha \nu \Bigl[ {\scriptsize\begin{gathered} a \\[-5pt] \swarrow \ \searrow \\[-5pt] a_{00} \qquad a_1 \end{gathered}} \Bigr]
+ (1-\alpha) \nu \Bigl[ {\scriptsize\begin{gathered} a \\[-5pt] \swarrow \ \searrow \\[-5pt] a_{01} \qquad a_1 \end{gathered}} \Bigr], $$

where $\alpha$ is given by

$$ \alpha = \frac{(a_1 - a_{00})(a_{01} - a_0)}{(a_1 - a_0)(a_{01} - a_{00})} \in (0, 1). $$

**3.** The final ingredient is the observation that any probability measure $\mu \in \mathcal{M}$ on $[0, 1]$ that averages to $p$ can be approximated by $\nu[\mathsf{T}]$. This follows from the binary splitting process (see [this](https://www.math.wisc.edu/%7Eroch/teaching_files/275b.1.12w/lect24-web.pdf), for instance), which is often adopted in the proof of the [Skorokhod's embedding theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Skorokhod%27s_embedding_theorem).

Here, we only outline the key idea. We will construct a sequence of binary trees $(\mathsf{T}_n)_{n=0}^{N}$ by running the following algorithm:

- We begin with the binary tree $\mathsf{T}_0$ which consists only of the root $([0, 1], p)$.
- Suppose that $\mathsf{T}_n$ is defined and satisfies $a = \mu[x \mid x \in I] = \frac{1}{\mu(I)} \int_{I} x \, \mu(\mathrm{d}x)$ for each node $(I, a)$ of $\mathsf{T}_n$.

  1. If $\mu(I) = \mu(\{a\})$ holds for all leaves $(I, a)$ of $\mathsf{T}_n$, we set $N = n$ and halt the algorithm.
  2. Otherwise, pick a leaf $(I, a)$ of $\mathsf{T}_n$ and set

     $$ a_0 = \mu[x \mid x \in I \cap [0, a)] \qquad\text{and}\qquad a_1 = \mu[x \mid x \in I \cap [a, 1]]. $$

     The two assumptions, $a = \mu[x \mid x \in I]$ and $\mu(I) \neq \mu(\{a\})$, shows that both $\mu(I \cap [0, a)) > 0$ and $\mu(I \cap [a, 1]) > 0$ hold true, and so, both $a_0$ and $a_1$ are well-defined. Moreover, with this choice, we have

     $$ \nu \Bigl[ {\scriptsize\begin{gathered} a \\[-5pt] \swarrow \ \searrow \\[-5pt] a_{0} \qquad a_{1} \end{gathered}} \Bigr] = \frac{\mu(I \cap [0, a))}{\mu(I)} \delta_{a_0} + \frac{\mu(I \cap [a, 1])}{\mu(I)} \delta_{a_1}. $$

     Then we set $\mathsf{T}_{n+1}$ as the binary tree obtained by inserting two children $(I \cap [0, a), a_0)$ and $(I \cap [a, 1], a_1)$ under the node $(I, a)$.
- If the algorithm does not halt in finite time, set $N = \infty$.

Then it can be proved that $\nu[\mathsf{T}_n]$ converges to $\mu$ weakly as $n \to N$. If we denote $\kappa_n$ for the probability measure obtained by applying the lemma to $\nu[\mathsf{T}_n]$, then any limit point of $(\kappa_n)_{n=0}^{N}$ as $n \to N$ will provide the desired probability measure associated with $\mu$.

Comment: Thank you very much for the proof. I think this is also generalization to higher dimensions but when I will deal with infinite dimension space it will be trickier. I found a nice proof that I put in an answer involving the concept of faces, you may want to check it out if you have time. Anyway I will give you the bounty because I like your proof.

Answer (score 1):

Your identificaton of the extreme points of $\mathcal M$ is correct.  A proof of the difficult part can be based on a theorem of R.G. Douglas. See my recent answer to [Two term martingales and their extreme points](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3825686/two-term-martingales-and-their-extreme-points/3827473#3827473), with a reference to a paper of A.F. Karr containing such a proof.

Comment: Thank you for the reference, The paper you provide will prove most useful.

Comment: Your reference proved most useful, I tried to summarize the result there and generalize to infinite dimensions, any review would be welcome.

Answer (score 1):

We can adapt the results in the paper "Extreme Points of Certain Sets of Probability Measures, with Applications" by A.F. Karr (https://www.jstor.org/stable/3689412) mentionned by @JohnDawkins to the following more general result.

Suppose that $X$ is a closed compact convex subset of a locally convex space $E$.

> **Definition.** The subset $F\subseteq X$ is called a face if for all $x\in F$ such that there is $y,z\in X$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$ with $x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z$, then $y,z\in F$.

One can show that faces are closed compact convex subsets of $X$ and that $x$ is extreme in $X$ if and only if $\{ x \}$ is a face. Indeed if $x$ is extreme and $\{ x \}$ is a face is really the same statement. We are now ready to characterize the extreme points of a linear subspace of $X$. Let $\mathcal F(A)$ be the set of faces of $A$.

> **Lemma.** Let $f$ be an affine functional from $X$ to some other vector topological space $Y$. Define $X_f=\{ x\in X:f(x)=0\}$, then $\mathcal F(X_f)=\{ F\cap X_f:F\in\mathcal F(X) \}$.

> **Corrolary.** $x$ is an extreme point of $X_f$ if and only if there exist a face $F\in\mathcal F(X)$ such that $F\cap X_f=\{x\}$.

Suppose that $F\in\mathcal F(X)$, then for $x\in F\cap X_f$, $y,z\in X_f$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$ such that $x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z$, we know that $y,z\in F$ which means that $x,z\in F\cap X_f$ and so $F\cap X_f$ is a face.

Suppose that $F\in\mathcal F(X_f)$ and let $G=\{ y\in X : \exists x\in F,z\in X,\lambda\in(0,1):x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z \}$, then we can show that $F=G\cap X_f$ and $G\in \mathcal F(X)$ which finishes the proof. To show the first statement, it is clear that any $y\in F$ is also in $G\cap X_f$ by taking $x=z=y$ and any $\lambda$. Now take $y\in G\cap X_f$, then there is $x\in F$, $z\in X$ and $\lambda\in(0,1)$ such that $x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z$, and since $\lambda\neq 1$, $z\in X_f$. But since $y$ and $z$ are in $X_f$, then they are in $F$ and in particular $y\in F$.

In order to show that $G\in\mathcal F(X)$, we take any $x\in G$ and any $y,z\in X$, $\lambda\in (0,1)$ such that $x=\lambda y+(1-\lambda)z$. Since $x\in G$ there is $x'\in F$, $z'\in X$ and $\lambda'$ such that \begin{align*}
x'&=\lambda'x+(1-\lambda')z'\\
&=\lambda'\lambda y+\lambda'(1-\lambda)z+(1-\lambda')z'\\
&=\alpha y+(1-\alpha)\tilde z
\end{align*}
with $\alpha=\lambda' \lambda\in(0,1)$ and $\tilde z =\frac{\lambda'(1-\lambda )z+(1-\lambda')z'}{1-\alpha}\in X$, this implies that $y\in G$ and similarly we can write $x'=\beta z+(1-\beta)\tilde y$ with $\beta=\lambda'(1-\lambda)\in(0,1)$ and $\tilde y=\frac{\lambda'\lambda y+(1-\lambda')z'}{1-\beta}\in X$ and so $z\in G$, so $G\in\mathcal F(X)$. $\square$

---

In my case we can have $X$ to be the set of probability measures over $[0,1]$ and if $f:\mu\rightarrow \int xd\mu(x)-p$ then $\mathcal M=X_f$. One can show that for any Borel measurable $A\subseteq [0,1]$, $F_A=\{ \int_A \delta_x d\mu(x):\mu(A)=1 \}$ is a face (it is all measures with support inside $A$) and all faces are of this form. Now we can also show that $F_A\cap X_f=\{ x\}$ if and only if $1\leq|A|\leq 2$ and $p$ is in the convex hull of $A$. This indeed gives the set that I mentioned in the question.